# issue while running command "cordova build android"

Tags: sfdcmobilesdk-android

I am getting error as
[Error: Failed to run "java -version", make sure that you have a JDK installed.
You can get it from: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads.
]
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: D:\testSFAndr\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat: Command failed with exit code 2
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: D:\testSFAndr\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat: Command failed with exit code 2
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\rohit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:131:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:1008:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1080:5)

I have already set Java_Home system variable.
Any kind of help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you ever find any solution? I too am facing the same problem

Answer (score 1):

I had a JRE installed in my system. After installing JDK7, I am able to run "cordova build android" command

Comment: Well done for following up on this.